# Play Framework Eclipse Project conversion error

Tags: eclipse, playframework, scala-ide, playframework-2.4

I am a newbie to play framework, just downloaded the Play 2.4.2, created a project using the

```
activator new
```

After that, I tried to convert project to eclipse, but the command

```
 activator eclipse
```

resulted in the error
[image]

I have converted it to eclipse project by starting `activator ui` and through activator web console, converted project to eclipse. But it in the UI also, I have seen the above error message, but it has converted to eclipse project.

Imported the project into eclipse and it is showing error in the Application.java file as shown below.
[image]

I have downloaded the Scala IDE, tried to import the project, still the same.
I have started the application from command line using

```
activator run
```

My app is listening on 9000, and refreshed the project in the IDE, still the cannot find symbol is unresolved.

The jump start is not smooth, How to resolve this?

Comment: You have to start activator in the folder of your project, the folder were your  project's `build.sbt` is. Go to this folder, type `activator clean` and afterwards `activator eclipse` (or `activator idea` for Intellij Idea) and your errors should vanish.

Comment: Inside project\plugins.sbt file added the following line
//Eclipse Plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE) is worth a read.  It explains adding some settings to the `build.sbt`:

```
$ activator new eclipse

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://typesafe.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
  2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
  3) minimal-java
  4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
  6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
> 5
OK, application "eclipse" is being created using the "play-java" template.

To run "eclipse" from the command line, "cd eclipse" then:
/Users/ben/projects/eclipse/activator run

To run the test for "eclipse" from the command line, "cd eclipse" then:
/Users/ben/projects/eclipse/activator test

To run the Activator UI for "eclipse" from the command line, "cd eclipse" then:
/Users/ben/projects/eclipse/activator ui

$ cd eclipse/
$ echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")' >> project/plugins.sbt
$ ./activator compile
...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (2998ms)
...
[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /Users/ben/projects/eclipse/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 36 s, completed 05-Jul-2015 14:00:25
$ ./activator eclipse
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ben/projects/eclipse/project
[info] Set current project to eclipse (in build file:/Users/ben/projects/eclipse/)
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] eclipse
$
```

Then import as an existing project within ScalaIDE (your Eclipse). Then all should be good.

Comment: I have added the lines into build.sbt as said, but when I say activator in CLI, it threw error : 
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
^
[error]Type error in expression
Project loading failed.

Comment: I have put in a walkthrough, I suspect you're using Windows, in which case, do the same except that with the "echo" line, you can use a text editor to add in the SBT Eclipse plugin line.

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem here. 
Scala template must be compiled first (after you start project and access any page) and then eclipse project must take reference library (contains these class) to solve error. 
Try to start project, access a page and re-generate eclipse project from activator console and import to IDE again.